# In enterprise guide, how do you re open a previous data steps output to view it?

Tags: sas

I'm using enterprise guide 4.3.

When you run a data step the resulting output opens in a spreadsheet like table.

Then when you run a `proc tabulate` or similar, the spreadsheet like view of the data disappears and the table comes up in SAS Report or HTML form etc.

You can then run further commands on that dataset that was created in the data step.

**Q. How can you get that spreadsheet like view of the dataset back? (assuming it's possible)**

I know you can run the data step again and it will display it but that seems really inefficient, especially if the data step had lots of computations involved. The data is obviously 'sitting there' given you can still interact with it (with proc tabulate etc). I was really surprised to see that it drops off from the process flow view.

Apologises if I've name things poorly above, I'm an R beginning to dabble in SAS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you run some code and the result comes up. Then you run some other piece of code, from the same Code node and the initial result gets removed from the process flow.

You can always find your dataset in the Server List. You can enable it by clicking `View -> Server List`.

There is also a trick that you can do. When you run your code and the dataset node is created in the process flow, you can do a simple query on it. Just do `Right click -> Filter and query` and make it do something simple that won't take too long.

Now, when you run your next piece of code, this node will not be replaced (at least this is what happens in EG 4.1).

Comment: Great, thanks dperetin, worked a charm. Pity you can't 'pin' or 'favourite' your WORK folder so it's right there. Tis a pain having to have the 5 folders above it all cascading down. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean viewing the resulting data set from a DATA STEP, choose View/Process Flow and double click on the data set you want to view. Also, within your program, log, data or result view, there should be tabs across the top that allow you to bring up the other items of the process flow.

Comment: Hi Carolina. I think you've missed my point (or I wasn't clear enough :) one of the two). If you run the datastep, as a portion of code ('Run Selection') the result opens as a spreadsheet (in a tab). If you then run a tabulate step (or similar), then the spreadsheet view (tab) disappears and the html tab opens with the table. At that point (because you only ran a chunk of code) the spreadsheet icon for that output disappears altogether from your process flow, and the tab for it is no longer across the top. I think @dperetin is on the money so I'll try that monday.

Comment: I understand what your problem is now...if you aren't going to run the  entire process, so that all results (data sets and reports) are generated, then separate those portions into individual programs (code nodes)...then you can run what you want without losing previous results.